# select2 not displaying array data properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-select2

i have this function to generate data

```
public function ajax_get_kota($idProv='')
{
    $kota = $this->registrasi_model->get_nama_kota($idProv);
    // echo json_encode(array_values($kota));
    $data = array();
    foreach($kota as $k){
        $data[] = '{id:'.$k->id_kab.','.'text:'.$k->nama.'}';
        // echo "{id: $k->id_kab, text: '$k->nama'}";
    }
    echo json_encode(array_values($data));
}
```

that return value like this

> ["{id:5103,text:KAB. BADUNG}", "{id:5106,text:KAB. BANGLI}", "{id:5108,text:KAB. BULELENG}", "{id:5104,text:KAB. GIANYAR}", "{id:5101,text:KAB. JEMBRANA}", "{id:5107,text:KAB. KARANGASEM}", "{id:5105,text:KAB. KLUNGKUNG}", "{id:5102,text:KAB. TABANAN}", "{id:5171,text:KOTA DENPASAR}"]

and i want those value above will be shown on my dropdown:
here's the code:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback <?php set_validation_style('Kota')?>">        
    <?php echo form_label('Kota / Kabupaten', 'kota', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-2')) ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <?php
            $atribut_kota = 'class="form-control dropKota"';
            echo form_dropdown('Kota', $namaKota, $values->Kota, $atribut_kota);
            set_validation_icon('Kota');
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (form_error('Kota')) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <?php echo form_error('Kota', '<span class="help-block">', '</span>');?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropProv").on("change", function(){
                var idProv = $(this).val();
                var baseUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>program/administrasi/registrasi/ajax_get_kota/'+idProv;
                var kota = [];
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl,
                    data: kota,
                    success: function(datas){
                        console.log(datas);
                        $(".dropKota").select2({
                            placeholder: "Pilih Kota",
                            data: datas //the data loads here
                        });                        },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

how do i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of object / array `select2` expects, but it looks like the json you are sending from php, is not getting parsed.

So to start you should change that:

```
$.ajax({
                url: baseUrl,
                // set the dataType so that jQuery will parse the json automatically
                dataType: 'json',
                data: kota,
                success: function(datas){
                    console.log(datas);
                    ...
```

Now you will send an array of objects to `select2` which is probably very close to what you need.

Comment: if i use `dataType: 'json'` all data will turn into `[object Object]`. i just found that `select2` use array format `id:123,name:abc` so if i change `id_kab` to `id` and `nama` into `name` and put the data in the select2 function it will work. but those data are from database how do i format it so `select2` can accept?

Comment: @HealMee That's why I used `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. About the contents of the data, you just need to loop over your `$kota` variable in php and add the right elements with the right keys to a new array. That array you can `json_encode` and send back to javascript.

Comment: I used `console.log()` and updated my codes, now i need to get rid the `"` between this `["{` from the generated data. how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to return JSON response from PHP as well as you need to specify JSON data type in AJAX request.

So your PHP code would look something like this,

```
public function ajax_get_kota($idProv='')
{
    $kota = $this->registrasi_model->get_nama_kota($idProv);
    $data = array();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array_values($kota));
}
```

And AJAX would look like this,

```
$.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl,
                    data: kota,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(datas){
                        // alert(datas);
                        $(".dropKota").select2({
                            placeholder: "Pilih Kota",
                            data: datas //the data loads here
                        });                        },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about php, but for me the code:

```
$("#dropdownId").select2("val", "your value");
```

is working for selecting one value in select2 dropdown using jquery js in a jsp page(java web project).